# user-friend relationship implementation with laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to implement a user-friend relationship like twitter for instance. from what i could catch online, it's an example of self-referencing many-to-many relationship.

First, I would like to understand how to model this relationship logically (e.g depict it using UML class diagram). then i would like to know how to implement it via eloquent.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of the UML:

```
        +------------------+
        |      Users       |
        +------------------+
        | - id: int        |
        | - username: str  |
        | - email: str     |
        | - password: str  |
        +------------------+
                 | 1..* 
                 |
        +------------------+
        |    Friendships   |
        +------------------+
        | - id: int        |
        | - user_id: int   |
        | - friend_id: int |
        +------------------+
```

To make this implementation, first start with the migration:

```
// Create the "users" table
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->timestamps();
});

// Create the "friendships" table
Schema::create('friendships', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('friend_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('friend_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Later, you can make the models:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    //$fillable..

    public function friendships()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Friendship::class);
    }
    
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friendships', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
    }
}

class Friendship extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'friendships';
    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    
    public function friend()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'friend_id');
    }
}
```

With this ORM you can do many actions like:

```
// Get a user's friendships
$user = User::find(1);
$friendships = $user->friendships;

// Get a user's friends
$user = User::find(1);
$friends = $user->friends;

// Add a friendship between two users
$user1 = User::find(1);
$user2 = User::find(2);
$friendship = new Friendship(['user_id' => $user1->id, 'friend_id' => $user2->id]);
$user1->friendships()->save($friendship);
```

You can use Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x), for more info about migrations, models, Eloquent: Relationships etc..